# Deserialize subclasses with Jackson by parent class field value

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I have a parent class:

```
open class NetworkMessage(var type: NetworkMessageType)
```

and a bunch of it's subclasses, like

```
class ConnectionAcceptedResponseMessage(
    val accepted: Boolean,
    val uid: String
) : NetworkMessage(NetworkMessageType.CONNECTION_ACCEPTED)
```

so every message type is clearly determined by parent class field value. Is there any way to deserialize concrete subclass using only annotations and without using treeNode?

Comment: Does `NetworkMessage` "know" about all subclasses?

Comment: What do you mean by "know"? This json objects are sent from C# client, so I created objects on both client and server that serialize in the same json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can do something like this on the parent class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConnectionAcceptedResponseMessage.class, name = "CONNECTION_ACCEPTED"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OtherResponseMessage.class, name = "OTHER")
})
```

I guess in Kotlin this will be similar.